# Installing PHP with MySQL support?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, redhat

I've got PHp installed from my hosting provider and it doesnt seem to have mysql support built in. I was redirected to an installation script:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Which installed mysql as a program, but phpinfo() still shows:

> Configure Command      './configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' .............................. '--without-mysql' '

What do I do next to have mysql support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install php-mysql:

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Then check /etc/php.d/mysql.ini file.
Tets php:

```
php -i | grep -i mysql
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
MySQL Support => enabled
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient 

php -r 'mysql_connect();'
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: Interesting - this sort of installed something, but no change in phpinfo() and no change in my application - "Installed:  php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5           Dependency Installed:  php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5"

Comment: test php: php -r 'mysql_connect();'

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Command line code on line 1

Comment: I dont know if it complicates things, but my root password is X, my mysql admin password is Y and the password for the database user for my applicaiton is Z.

Comment: @matt_tm - that error means you've got your mysql support working.  Otherwise you'd get some version of a "method not found" error.  You can sort out the authentication issues in your php code.

Comment: You know - the problem 'sorted' itself out... I think the hosting provider did something and I'm seeing mysql stuff show up in phpinfo(). Not sure what they did though...